# Tools for removing ceramic tile baseboard from concrete wall?

Tags: tools, brick, baseboard, ceramic-tile

I want to replace my tile baseboard with a PVC one, from what I gathered I should be able to remove it with a chisel or a crowbar but I've tried with a chisel and all I can do is chip away the ceramic until I don't have any edges. It seems like the tiles where glued with mortar. Am I doing something wrong or should I get a crowbar/ rent an air hammer?

Comment: Something too aggressive like an air hammer could easily start digging into the wall instead of the concrete if you're not careful. Not saying not to use one, just be careful with it!

Comment: If it is held with mortar or thinset, it should pop off with a chisel and hammer. Do not try to drive the chisel vertically from the top. You need to start the chisel at a 45 degree angle in the top corner of  tiles not chipped off yet. Don't try to get off one at a time to start, one tile helps hold the next in. Try tapping across the top of a number of tiles, all you need to see is a hairline crack started Tile does not like hard vibrations like you are doing. Once you see the hairline crack, then you can start making the chisel more vertical as the crack opens up.

Answer (score 3):

You need a thin prybar. I use the Titan brand, but I'm sure there are others around. They are perfect exactly for this purpose. Use them so much I have to buy a new set every few months. Totally worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Not an Air Hammer. Much too powerful, not easy to handle.

An electric hammer will do.

It will replace your labor intensive work with hammer and chisel.

While the tiles come of relatively easy, the mortar is the hard one to remove and it will take long time.